# How to deal with sentence without event triple?

Tags: knowledge-graph

I am new to machine learning, I want to extract event triple from news headlines. But there are many news headlines without event triples, only containing subject and predicate. How shall I deal with these kind of sentences?

Comment: one approach is to take the object (for example) as implied, having a separate category

Comment: another approach is to take them as they are, wihtout object in a category by themselves

Comment: @NikosM. Thank you very much, I want to extract at least subject and predicate. I tried to use OpenIE but it seems not able to extract subject and predicate from a news headline if there is no object, i.e. no event triple. Do you know what tools I can use to at least extract subject and predicate when there is no object?

Comment: I would train a model to meet my requirements if none of available tools meet them, eg see https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-event-extraction-f20d634661d3